# How update the component when the createAsyncThunk return a promise (react/redux toolkit)

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have i async function that send a request to the database to update a count, and this function return a promise like that

```
{Nome: "a", Valor: 1700, Historico: "teste", Documento: 1, DataEmissao: "2020-12-24T00:00:00.000Z", …}
DataEmissao: "2020-12-24T00:00:00.000Z"
DataVencimento: "2020-12-24T00:00:00.000Z"
Documento: 1
Historico: "teste"
Nome: "a"
Valor: 1700
createdAt: "2021-03-30T14:13:31.404Z"
id: "6063320bafd21c22e45f404c"
updatedAt: "2021-03-31T14:56:43.873Z"
__v: 0
__proto__: Object
```

this is my data updated, but i don't know how i can send this data to overwhite the old data in my component and store, my component just update when i reload de page and my app send request again to load the database data, i tried to use createEntytyAdapter but i could not.

This is my code

```
export const editCount = createAsyncThunk('contas/editCount', async (data) => {
    const dados = data;
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/teste/' + dados.documento, {

        Documento: dados.documento,
        Nome: dados.nome,
        Valor: dados.valor,
        Historico: dados.historico,
        DataEmissao: dados.dataEmissao,
        DataVencimento: dados.dataVencimento

    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('teste', response.data)
        return response.data;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
})
const ContasReducer = createSlice({
    name: sliceName,
    initialState: {
        contas: [],
        status: null
    },
    reducers: {

    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        
       builder.addCase(fetchCounts.fulfilled , (state, { payload }) => {
            state.contas = payload
            state.status = 'success'
        })
        builder.addCase(fetchCounts.pending , (state, action) => {
            state. status = 'Loading'
            state. contas = [{}]
        })
        builder.addCase(createAcount.fulfilled , (state, action) => {
            state = action.payload
            console.log('action payload', action.payload)
        })
        // this is my reducer
        builder.addCase(editCount.fulfilled , (state, action) => {
            state.conta = action.meta.arg;
            console.log('reducer',action.meta.arg)
        })

    }
})

//My component 
 function SalvarDados() {
        
        Dispatch(
            editCount({
                documento: Documento,
                nome: Nome,
                valor: Valor,
                historico: Historico,
                dataEmissao: new Date(DataEmissao),
                dataVencimento: new Date(DataVencimento),
            })
        )
        props.CloseModal()
    }
```

@solved
My function async that call the api was not returned the promise because the .then was not in front the axios.post, my code fixed

```
export const editCount = createAsyncThunk('contas/editCount', async (data) => {
    const dados = data;
    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/teste/' + dados.documento, {

        Documento: dados.documento,
        Nome: dados.nome,
        Valor: dados.valor,
        Historico: dados.historico,
        DataEmissao: dados.dataEmissao,
        DataVencimento: dados.dataVencimento

    })
    return response.data;
})
//My extra reducer
builder.addCase(editCount.fulfilled , (state, {payload}) => {
            const [data] = payload;
            const conta = state.contas.findIndex((obj) => obj.Documento === data.Documento)
            const newConta = [ ... state.contas].splice(conta, data)
            state.contas = payload;
        
        })
```

I hope this post can helpe someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `createAysncThunk` doesn't actually return the data.  The `return response.data;` is the return for the `.then` callback function, not for the thunk itself. You need to add `return` in front of `axios.post` to return the whole promise.

```
return axios.post(...)
  .then((response) => response.data);
```

If you `catch` errors here then your thunk will always be `fulfilled` instead of `rejected`.  It is better to let the errors be thrown.  The middleware will catch them.

---

This is an `async` function, so you can also `await` the `Promise`.

```
const response = await axios.post(...);
return response.data;
```